# Invalid data found when processing input on ffmpeg m4s to mp4 transfer

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, file-extension, file-format

[The result of the power shell window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQEFv.png)

I saw a post on here about converting m4s to mp4 and I have followed the steps of concatenating all the files into another m4s file that I called all.m4s and when I use the command ffmpeg -i allm4s.m4s -c copy video.mp4. I made the combined m4s file by coding an exe to add all the m4s files that have the word video in them to the m4s file. Here is the source code written in c# if you compile the code then that is the code I have used to make the m4s

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;

namespace files
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string dir = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
            string[] info = Directory.GetFiles(dir);
            Console.WriteLine(dir + "\\allm4s.m4s");
            Console.ReadKey();
            foreach (string name in info)
            {
                if (Path.GetFileName(name).Contains(".m4s") && Path.GetFileName(name).Contains("video"))
                {
                    using (Stream srcStream = File.OpenRead(name))
                    {
                        using (Stream destStream = File.OpenWrite(dir+"\\allm4s.m4s"))
                        {
                            srcStream.CopyTo(destStream);
                            Console.WriteLine(destStream+name);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

I think if there is to be an issue it is to do with this allm4s.m4s file as the file size is about 1.5mb even though each segment m4s is about 750kb each and there are quite a lot.If anyone has a way of adding concatenating lots of files together through a program/application that would be useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting that error because you might be concatenating videos of different dimensions.
all your input file's full names are stored in input array

**Java Program**

```
String inputStr="";
String stream="";

for(int index=0;index<input.length;index++){
  inputStr=inputStr+" -i "+input[index];
  stream =stream +"["+index+":v]"+"["+index+":a]"; //gets audio and video stream of file
}
 String command = "ffmpeg "+inputStr+" -filter_complex \" "+stream+" concat=n="+(index-1)+ \
 ":v=1:a=1 [v] [a] \" "+ "-map \"[v]\" -map \"[a]\" outputfile.m4s"

 Runtime.getRuntime(command).exec().waitFor();//runs ffmpeg command to concat all files
```

Comment: The error does not indicate the the broken input is due to concatenating different dimensions. Secondly, the question was tagged [tag:c#], so a java solution may not be helpful.